# Filter courses on Moodle 2.7

Tags: filter, moodle

I am wondering if there is any plugin available for Moodle 2.7 which allows admin to add some attributes to courses and create a widget to filter the courses by thoses attributes.

For example, we would like to allow users to filter courses by their price, content, dates etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try this block :https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=block_course_overview_campus

Comment: Many thanks @gnuwings, the plugin works quite well but it works as a block, and so on does not update the main page course list, it just shows a list behind the filters (inside the block). We were looking for something which updates the main course list...

Answer (score 0):

The block gnuwings provided will actually solve your issue when configured within Moodle correctly.
What you should do afterwards, is enable the 'My Moodle' page for every user. To find this setting, you should use the search function for the site admin.

My Moodle allows you to place blocks in the center of the screen, so you can edit the default My Moodle page to show this block. I would personally recommend turning the feature that allows students to edit their own My Moodle page off, as this will make it harder for you to manage this page in the future (without modifications to the database).

To edit the default 'My' page, in Moodle 2.7, go to site administration, appearance, default my page.
To enable this view by default, go to site administration -> appearance -> navigation, and update the value of 'Default home page for users'.